# HHVM w/ FastCGI vs. Uploading via WordPress

Tags: php, fastcgi, chown, hhvm

I successfully installed nginx, HHVM (running with FastCGI) etc. on an Ubuntu 15.10 installation, and HHVM is, in itself, running fine. My /var/www directory is owned by my user and group (e.g. sam:sam), so I can access it via SSH and SFTP and change files accordingly. When now running a CMS like WordPress, it obviously runs as the web server (www-data), and thus cannot change/add/delete files from its backend (e.g. upload files, update WordPress/plugins) as would be required unless I change user and group ownership to www-data.

Is there a way to solve this to be able to change files via PHP and SSH without letting the web server run with a user that has obviously sudo rights? I believe 'normal' PHP running as FastCGI is able to circumvent the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the situation correctly you should change the ownership of the files to the `www-data` user.  Since you have sudo permissions you can add your user (sam) to the `www-data` group and still be able to do what you need to do.

To add your user to the `www-data` group:

```
usermod -a -G www-data sam
```

To change ownership of all the files to `www-data` user and group:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

To add group write permissions to all files in `/var/www`:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
```

Comment: Just to really get it. I already added my user to the www-data group, plus changed ownership of the data folder to www-data:www-data. When logging in through an FTP client, I am not able to alter files this way, even though **sam** is part of the www-data group as well (along the **sam** group). Did I do something wrong? Would I need sudo to change files?

Comment: The files and folders need to have group write permissions.  The following command with apply that to all files in /var/www:



"sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www"

Comment: 775 (or g+w) does the trick, I believe, I had it on 755 which is a bit more secure as far as I know. This way I can add more users (for subsequent FTP users), add them to the www-data group and stay flexible. Please add the chmod command to your answer, just to make it perfect for others in hunt of the same answer :)!

Comment: Done!  Glad it helped!